# Command line to run two Excel files in sequence

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line

I have two excel files, `C:\A.xlsm` and `C:\B.xlsm`, both have macros defined in "Workbook_Open()", when opened, will run, make some computation, then exit.

Is it possible to use command line, batch file, etc, to run the two excel files, in sequence?

By **run**, I mean B shall start after A finish.

I understand that Windows Scheduled Task can define multiple Actions, which will *start* in sequence, but the next action doesn't wait the previous one to *finish*. So this is not enough here.

Comment: In your macro in first file put the last statement (before exiting) as Shell ("cmd /c C:\B.xlsm")

Comment: @pat2015 true, that would work. but really would rather not go this way creating hidden dependencies unless there's no other way out.

Comment: Would a batch file with `cmd /c C:\A.xlsm` followed by `cmd /c C:\B.xlsm` not do what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this batch file

```
start /wait excel.exe a.xlsx
b.xlsx
pause
```